# Android Spinner: Get selected custom object

Tags: android, casting, xamarin.android, spinner, selecteditem

In this simple example I will show you how I usually get the selected item of a spinner, which is filled with items from a custom class.

```
// Simple sample class
public class StringWithIndex
{
    public string itemString;
    public int itemIndex;

    public StringWithIndex(string stringPart, int indexPart)
    {
        itemString = stringPart;
        itemIndex = indexPart;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return itemString;
    }
}

// Create sample list
List<StringWithIndex> spinnerItems = new List<StringWithIndex>();
spinnerItems.Add(new StringWithIndex("A", 1));
spinnerItems.Add(new StringWithIndex("B", 2));
spinnerItems.Add(new StringWithIndex("C", 3));

// Create Spinner
Spinner spinner = new Spinner(Context);
var spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<StringWithIndex>(Context, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, spinnerItems);
spinner.Adapter = spinnerAdapter;

// Spinner Item selected
 spinner.ItemSelected += (sender, e) =>
{
    var pos = spinner.SelectedItemPosition;
    var item = spinnerItems[pos];
    // do something with item
};
```

I know the selected item position and search in the list which is used for the adapter for the selected item.

So my question is, is there a way to access the object directly, without searching in the original list?
For example a cast of the selected item does not work

```
var itemString = (spinner.SelectedItem as StringWithIndex).itemString;
```

I do not know the benefits of accessing the item without the list right now, but everytime I am implementing a spinner I ask myself this question.

**EDIT**:
My thoughts are heading to use SelectedItem. I know there many ways to use the position in any kind of passed list or overriden method from the adapter.

Comment: could it work ?

Comment: as I mentioned in my Edits, I was looking for an alternative way that uses SelectedItem from the spinner. Your solution still just searches the list that is passed to the spinner (in your case through the adapter)

Comment: if you want use SelectedItem from the spinner,you need do some conversion,i update my answer,you could check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So my question is, is there a way to access the object directly,
>   without searching in the original list?

you could try this:

```
Spinner spinner = new Spinner(Context);
var spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<StringWithIndex>(Context, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, spinnerItems);
spinner.Adapter = spinnerAdapter;

// Spinner Item selected
spinner.ItemSelected += (sender, e) =>
  {        
    var obj = e.Parent.SelectedItem;
    var item = obj.GetType().GetProperty("Instance").GetValue(obj) as StringWithIndex;
    var itemString = item .itemString;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not searching, when selecting item then you are geting position of item, and when you have position you can take item from list with certain position

```
val adapter = ArrayAdapter(context, R.layout.your_custom__header_layout,
                   yourModels)

            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.costom_layout_of_item
            spinner.adapter = adapter


spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
                override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View,
                                            position: Int, id: Long) {
                    val stringWithIndex = parent.getItemAtPosition(position) as StringWithIndex
                }

                override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {
                    // Empty
                }
            }
```